# How to connect four analog microphones to Raspberry Pi GPIO?

Tags: gpio, pwm, analog-to-digital, microphone

I have four microphones that has pins: VCC, GND and Analog Data. I need to connect it to Raspberry Pi (I need it for detection direction to source of sound). As I know, GPIO doesn't have analog inputs, only digital inputs. So, is it possible to connect that microphones to Raspberry Pi without ADC?

I need to connect this microphones to RPi: https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/analog/audio/MAX4466.html

Comment: there is no way to get audio without an ADC and the ability to process it. However, if you are not looking to process the sound, but more just to know that "A sound" happened, the digital version might be able to work, but I suspect you will run into many issues with that.

Comment: You should [edit] your question and add the brand and type of the microphones or provide a link to the documentation. Describe how you want to analyze the microphone signal. Is "Analog Data" an analog signal or maybe PWM? If it is really analog, it doesn't make sense to connect it to a digital input.

Comment: Ok, you can write it as answer and I will accept it.

I ordered 12bit and 16bit ADCs. I hope that accuracy will be enough.

Comment: @Bodo This microphones https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/analog/audio/MAX4466.html

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide requested information or clarification, don't use comments for this purpose.

Comment: The MAX4466 isn't a microphone - it is a *pre-amp* for a microphone. Meaning that its output is just baseband audio - to be fed to another amplifier stage typically to drive speakers/headphones, etc. I don't mean to pry, but if you'd provide some additional information re your overall application, perhaps we could offer something **useful**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Pi has no analogue GPIO.

You need additional circuitry between the Pi's digital GPIO and the microphones.  The simplest way would be to add a SPI based ADC such as the MCP3008.